# Getting http in the Location-header when the original request was made over https

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, https, undertow

My questions:

1) Why do I get http as the scheme in the Location-header when the original request from the browser was made with https?

2) Is this an wildfly load balancer problem?

> My Request Header is:

```
method: POST
scheme: https
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 39
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
origin: https://10.43.201.207
referer: https://10.43.201.207/myapp/login.html
```

> My Response Header is:

```
content-length: 0
date: Thu, 03 Jan 2019 04:55:42 GMT
location: http://10.43.201.207/myapp/dashboard.html?init=1
server: WildFly/12
set-cookie: APP_AUTH=leTPWYd1222zsrrtRRtgpuEWEWc7pR0CBuNPYPT5QHbGn_Db7ICK; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
set-cookie: JSESSIONID="leTee33333PWYdSDSDweetRRtgpuc7pR0CBuNPYPT5QHbGn_Db7ICK.master-0:master-server"; Version=1; Path=/myapp; Secure; HttpOnly
status: 302
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by: Undertow/1
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: That appears to be a redirect.

Comment: Hi Robert , yeah correct it is redirect only , but we are not saying like redirect with http. In our LoginServlet Code we are writing like below in doPost method `response.sendRedirect("dashboard.html" ); `

Comment: I did a bit of research before commenting on your question.  It seems to suggest that a redirect can occur before the TLS handshake is realized.

Comment: So should I need to change my LoginServlet code something like if it is **http** replace with **https** ? or there is some load balancer configuration am I missing?

Comment: Hi I didn't get any clue on this , why response header is coming as http , can anyone suggest me here how can I come out from this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the load balancer stripping the TLS off and forwarding the request to the app as HTTP? If so, then the app, when performing a redirect, it is probably using the same protocol that it received the request on.

If that's the case, either get the app to force `https`, or get the load balancer to rewrite the responses coming back through.

You may need to set `proxy-address-forwarding="true"` and/or `request_header_add X-Forwarded-Proto https` .

Comment: Hi Mennon, how can I check this : - load balancer is stripping the TLS off and forwarding the request to the app as HTTP?

Comment: You could check where the TLS certificate is set up - if it's on the load balancer, then it's dealing with the decryption, if it's on the app (or app server) instead, then that is. Or if it wasn't you setting up TLS, ask the person/team that did.

Comment: @Mennon and @ Subodh , we have added `proxy-address-forwarding="true"` in wildfly application server configuration , it worked

Comment: another simple fix would be not to set the scheme in the Location header field at all

Answer (score 3):

Below is the detailed solution explanation for the above problem:

We have a load-balancer sitting in front of two wildfly servers. The load-balancer handles the SSL handshake and forces all traffic over `https` , the wildfly nodes do not have certificates on them and traffic between load balancer and servers is unencrypted, the wildfly nodes know nothing about the SSL.The communication between load balancer and wildfly nodes is via `http` protocol.

When a user hits a protected page  e.g. https://someip/app

Request flow is as below:

- Client browser to load balancer via `https`
- Load balancer to wildlfy nodes via `http` protocol .
- Added  `proxy-address-forwarding="true"` in wildlfy server node's  `http`
  listener

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to have you load balancer add the Strict-Transport-Security header to the server response, for example:

```
Strict-Transport-Security max-age=300;
```

This will effectively tell the client that he should always use https to contact your server.